# Hadoop Basics:Number of map tasks mappers reduce tasks reducers

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, internals, mapper, reducers

What is the difference between a mapper and a map task?
Similarly, a reducer and a reduce task?
Also, how are number of mappers,maptasks,reducers,reducetasks determined during the execution of a mapreduce task?
Give interrelationships between them if there is any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply map task is an instance of Mapper. Mapper and reducer are methods in mapreduce jobs.

When we run a mapreduce job, number of map tasks spawned  depends on the number blocks(number of blocks depend on input splits) in the input. However the number of reduce tasks can be specified in the mapreduce driver code. Either it can be specified by setting property mapred.reduce.tasks in the job configuration object or `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job#setNumReduceTasks(int reducerCount);` method can be used.

In the old JobConf API `setNumMapTasks()` method was there. But `setNumMapTasks()` method is removed in the new API `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job`with the intension of number of mappers should be calculated based on the input splits.

Comment: can number of mappers also be specified by using mapred.map.tasks and setNumMapTasks?

Comment: I have modified the answer

Comment: also,how can i check the actual number of mappers/reducers tasks running for a particular job?

Comment: Number of map/reduce tasks will be there in Jobtracker's WebUI